# How to retrieve the version id of an uploaded file (iOS)?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket with versioning enabled. When I upload a file using `AWSS3TransferUtility` I need to return the version id that was created for that upload. I don't see it returned in the `AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask`.

In the REST interface it is returned as a [header](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/objectPutVersions.html). I need the same functionality for iOS uploads. How is it returned in the iOS API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to retrieve `versionId` using `AWSS3TransferUtility`. You need to use `AWSS3` and call [`- headObject:`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3.html#//api/name/headObject:) to retrieve it. We will explore the ways to expose the response object in the transfer utility for the future release.